# Appfog - how to install latest version of Nodejs

Tags: appfog

In Appfog how to install the latest version of Nodejs/ and on the services provided, can Mongodb be upgraded to 2.4.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppFog does not support SPECIFIC versions of node, just version "families".

For example, to use 0.8.x, use the CLI:

```
af push --runtime=node08
```

This would give you 0.8.14 (at the time of this writing)

MongoDB 2.x support is planned in their road map...

See:

- https://docs.appfog.com/languages/node
- https://docs.appfog.com/roadmap#services

Comment: is there a time line of Node 0.10 and Mongo 2.x support

Answer (score 1):

Actually AppFog now has Node 0.10 and MongoDB 2.4.8.